# How to call code to be run on specific worker thread from Windows Phone 8 UI thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8

My application is derived from a Windows Phone 8 Direct3D Xaml sample, where a C# program instantiates a WinPRT component that contains a Direct3D device. The C# code runs on the UI thread and the component code runs on a separate application thread. The WinPRT component works with a C++ pre-compiled library that contains variables declared per-thread, **static __declspec(thread)**.

The variables get initialized when needed in the application thread, but the shutdown (caused by the lifecycle Closing event) is called on the UI thread. The shutdown process uses the wrong set of per-thread variables which haven't been initialized and causes a crash.

I haven't found any method on the WinPRT component that gets called on the application thread during shutdown. I was hoping to find one to hook my stuff into but there doesn't seem to be any.

So, how do I call the shutdown code to be run on the application thread from the UI thread?

WinPRT severely limits the threading functionality available to me. I haven't been able to find a workable solution. I looked at the Dispatcher class, but on WinPRT it's only used to run code on the UI thread from a worker thread and not vice versa. What other options might there be?

Comment: Is `SynchronizationContext` available?

Comment: Why are the variables not initialized on the UI thread?  How would you be able to tell which thread the variables were initialized on if if wasn't the UI thread?  If it's not a UI thread, you can't really marshal back to that thread.  the best you can do is cause the thread to wait (on something like a `AutoResetEvent`) then signal the waiting thread from the UI thread (maybe `AutoResetEvent.Set`)  see http://bit.ly/W0ElGZ for a similar example with `ManualResetEventSlim`

Comment: They are not used on the C# UI thread. The variables are basically just used on the C++ side which runs on the application thread.